# PowerApps dynamic condition

Tags: concatenation, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

Hi I am trying to filter a table based on a dynamic condition. I have a table called Table_Collegas that has columns Email, TrainingA, TrainingB, TrainingC, TrainingD etc. I also have a TextLabel called Next_training which displays the training that is coming up next (in the format "TrainingA").  I have this code for filtering emails:

```
Concat(
    Filter(
        Table_Collegas,
        'TrainingC' = "nee"
    ),
    Email,
    ";"
)
```

Now instead of manually typing TrainingC = "nee", I would like to select the column that correspongs to Next_training. So if Next_training says TrainingA the condition for the filter should be TrainingA = "nee", or if the label says TrainingB then it should be TrainingB = "nee" etc. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can try using switch case inside the filter condition and each case can refer to your respective Column